# Sorting a list of lines such that they are successively connected

Tags: graphs-and-networks, sorting

I have a list of line segments of the form $\{u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_n\}$, where $u_{k}$ is of the form $\{\{a_k,b_k\},\{c_k,d_k\}\}$. I want to sort them as $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$ in such a way that Last[$v_{k}$]=First[$v_{k+1}$].

I tried the following:

```
u = {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{5, 6}, {4, 5}}, {{2, 3}, {5, 6}}};
Sort[u, #1[[2]] == #2[[1]] &]
> {{{5, 6}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {5, 6}}}
```

But this did **not** work.
Is there a fast way to sort such an array?

Comment: `Sort[u]` would give `{{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{5, 6}, {4, 5}}}` which, I believe, is what you want

Comment: @eldo Not really. For instance, with `Graphics[Arrow[Sort[{{{1,2},{-2,3}},{{5,6},{4,5}},{{5,6},{-2,3}}}]]]` I want to see a connected and directed path.

Answer (score 4):

```
hPath = Partition[FindHamiltonianPath[UndirectedEdge @@@ #], 2, 1] &;
```

Thanks: @azerbajdzan for the correction in [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/292062/sorting-a-list-of-lines-such-that-they-are-succesively-connected/292063?noredirect=1#comment725621_292063).

***Examples:***

```
u1  = {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{5, 6}, {4, 5}}, {{2, 3}, {5, 6}}};

u2 =  {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{0, -1}, {4, 5}}, {{2, 3}, {0, -1}}};

hPath @  u1
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{5, 6}, {4, 5}}}
> ```

```
hPath @ u2
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {0, -1}}, {{0, -1}, {4, 5}}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
tSort = Partition[TopologicalSort[DirectedEdge @@@ #], 2, 1] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
u1  = {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{5, 6}, {4, 5}}, {{2, 3}, {5, 6}}};

u2 =  {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{0, -1}, {4, 5}}, {{2, 3}, {0, -1}}};

tSort @ u1
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{5, 6}, {4, 5}}}
> ```

```
tSort @ u2
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {0, -1}}, {{0, -1}, {4, 5}}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you vry much. Why do you think I get this unexpected arrow? https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/bkarpuz/Published/topologicalsort-error.nb

Comment: @bkarpuz, @kglr: Use the version with `FindHamiltonianPath` and then use `UndirectedEdge` instead of `DirectedEdge`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I coded. Here, $u$ has a list of lines. $v$ is the list of directed lines. To this end, the initial line segment must be specified, i.e., $v_{1}=u_{15}$ below.

```
u={{{42.225,2.74221},{40.6758,2.61411}},{{35.8258,2.42011},{34.7103,2.37161}},
{{40.0938,2.58501},{38.7358,2.51711}},{{33.6806,2.30737},{34.7103,2.37161}},
{{43.3275,2.86894},{42.225,2.74221}},{{32.4793,2.26491},{33.6806,2.30737}},
{{31.3595,2.21913},{32.4793,2.26491}},{{37.0383,2.46861},{35.8258,2.42011}},
{{43.9156,2.97301},{43.3275,2.86894}},{{30.5079,2.15657},{31.3595,2.21913}},
{{28.5811,2.01504},{29.4814,2.08117}},{{38.7358,2.51711},{37.0383,2.46861}},
{{44.4976,3.25431},{43.9156,2.97301}},{{40.6758,2.61411},{40.0938,2.58501}},
{{27.7263,1.93511},{28.5811,2.01504}},{{29.4814,2.08117},{30.5079,2.15657}}};
v=Table[Null,{k,1,Length[u]}];
Graphics[{Arrowheads[Small],Arrow[u]}]
v[[1]]=u[[15]];
u=Drop[u,{15}];
For[i=2,i<=Length[v],i++,
 For[j=1,j<=Length[u],j++,
  If[(Last[v[[i-1]]]==First[u[[j]]]||Last[v[[i-1]]]==Last[u[[j]]]),
   v[[i]]=If[Last[v[[i-1]]]==First[u[[j]]],u[[j]],Reverse[u[[j]]]]
  ];
  If[(Last[v[[i-1]]]==First[u[[j]]]||Last[v[[i-1]]]==Last[u[[j]]]),
   u=Drop[u,{j}]];
  ]
 ]
Graphics[{Arrowheads[Small],Arrow[v]}]
```